# How to use regex with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

I want to fetch the latest 64 bit Git for Windows using the `Invoke-WebRequest` command and here's the Regex for it `https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest/download/Git-([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)-64-bit\.exe`

(The 64 bit binaries are named like `Git-[numbershere]-64-bit.exe`, for example `Git-2.34.1-64-bit.exe`)

Now, I don't know how to pair this with `Invoke-WebRequest` to make it work. Can someone help?

Comment: URLs and regexes don't combine. You can't ask a server for a URL matching a regex of some kind. You have to actually know the exact URL in advance before accessing it. This could be done in various ways, like extracting it from another page where this URL is listed (and then you could use the regex to match that URL) but you can't feed it directly to `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507163/how-to-use-regex-with-invoke-webrequest/70507539#comment124635064_70507163): **you don't**

Instead, you could use [GitHub's public API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-the-latest-release) to fetch metadata about the latest release, then pick the appropriate url from there:

```
# fetch metadata for latest release
$latestRelease = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest" 

# enumerate included assets, find the appropriate one
$exe64bit = $latestRelease.assets |Where-Object name -like 'Git-*-64-bit.exe'

# output the appropriate browser URL
$exe64bit.browser_download_url
```